# Writing a log bespoke log reader in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, logging

I am trying to create a log reader. The data looks like so:

2017-11-27 13:24:41,791 [8] INFO  CTSipEndpoint.CLogger.provider.gsiplib [(null)] - -00001 [Info] Info    | 4744    | REGISTERdialog[1] 2-e:5;t:1-3 (dn:85188)

2017-11-27 13:24:41,791 [8] INFO  CTSipEndpoint.CLogger.provider.gsiplib [(null)] - -00001 [Info] Info    | 4744    | REGISTERdialog[1] event 2 REG/accepted

I am trying to do the following:

1. Return only lines in the last 48 hours to query further.
2. From above return any lines that contain the following phrases: "error"
   "device","does not exist", "Could not identify speaker!","warn"

So far i have only been able to get this to work in an inefficient way, which runs against the file for each phrase and appends an array. Unfortunately this means that the date time becomes non-sequential. I need to now sort the content object at the end of the script to it be in sequence, or find a way to run this query smarter. Here is my script for reference:

```
$logfile =  "C:\users\test\desktop\programlogs.log" 
$content = ""
cat $logfile |
Select-String "ERROR" -SimpleMatch |
  select -expand line |
   foreach {
              $_ -match '(.+)\s\[(ERROR)\]\s(.+)'| Out-Null 
              $error_time = [datetime]($matches[1]).split(",")[0]
              if ($error_time -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2))  {
               $content += $_ + "`n"
               } 
            }

cat $logfile |
Select-String "device" -SimpleMatch |
  select -expand line |
   foreach {
              $_ -match '(.+)\s\[(device)\]\s(.+)'| Out-Null 
              $error_time = [datetime]($matches[1]).split(",")[0]
              if ($error_time -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2))  {
               $content += $_ + "`n"
               } 
            }           


cat $logfile |
Select-String "does not exist" -SimpleMatch |
  select -expand line |
   foreach {
              $_ -match '(.+)\s\[(does not exist)\]\s(.+)'| Out-Null 
              $error_time = [datetime]($matches[1]).split(",")[0]
              if ($error_time -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2))  {
               $content += $_ + "`n"
               } 
            }


cat $logfile |
Select-String "Could not identify speaker!" -SimpleMatch |
  select -expand line |
   foreach {
              $_ -match '(.+)\s\[(Could not identify speaker!)\]\s(.+)'| Out-Null 
              $error_time = [datetime]($matches[1]).split(",")[0]
              if ($error_time -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2))  {
               $content += $_ + "`n"
               } 
            }           

cat $logfile |
Select-String "Warn" -SimpleMatch |
  select -expand line |
   foreach {
              $_ -match '(.+)\s\[(Warn)\]\s(.+)'| Out-Null 
              $error_time = [datetime]($matches[1]).split(",")[0]
              if ($error_time -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-2))  {
               $content += $_ + "`n"
               } 
            }                   


            $content = $content | select -uniq
            $file = "c:\temp\shortenedlog.txt"
            $content| Add-Content -Path $file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short take, let me know if this helps or if needs tweaking:

```
$newlog=@()
$logfile =  get-content C:\temp\programlogs.log
$searchFor="error","device","does not exist","Could not identify speaker!","warn"
foreach($line in $logfile){
    if($line.Length -gt 18){
        $datetime=date $line.substring(0,$line.indexof(","))
        if(((date)-$datetime).TotalHours -lt 49){
            $keep=$false
            foreach($item in $searchFor){
                if($line.contains($item)){ $keep=$true }
            } 
            if ($keep){$newlog+=$line}
        }
    }
}

$newlog | sort | % {add-content C:\temp\NewLog.log $_}
```

Comment: Hi,

Unfortunately i just get error codes with the above code:

Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Length cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: length"
At C:\Users\username\Desktop\LogReader.ps1:5 char:5
+     $datetime=date $line.substring(0,$line.indexof(","))
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Sorry about that, must be some blank lines in the log.  I updated the script.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Ended up going for a simple solution as the file was massive and was taking too long to iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution which I have fed in the days i am interested in, followed by the search criteria. Used this solution as works quickly.

```
#Set parameters.
$File = "c:\temp\RefinedLogs.txt"
$DateParam = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$DateParam1 = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$SearchForDate = @("$dateparam", "$dateparam1")
$SearchFor=@("error","device","does not exist","Could not identify speaker!","warn")

#Filter file with dates set in $SearchForDate.
$DateFiltered = Get-Content '.\MyAPP.log' | Select-String -Pattern $SearchForDate -SimpleMatch


#Filter variable for phrases set in $SearchFor.
$Content = $DateFiltered | Select-String -Pattern $SearchFor -SimpleMatch 

#Make results readable
ForEach($line in $content){
    $Object = "$line" + "`n"
    $FinalResult +=  $Object
    }

#Output results.
write-host $FinalResult
```